# @requestmapping feature in pure asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to build a web application compatible with Java and .NET platform.

It's built on a pure asp.net web project (no mvc3+), and the common way I invoke the webservice methods is to use Ajax, providing the url value ( like url : "FullPathOfWebservice/Methods" ) to it.

However, in Java platform, I invoke a specific method through just url. Spring Framework makes this possible with @Requestmapping annotation right above the target method.

I want to use the same feature in .NET platform as well. ( Please don't say use Spring framework for .NET, I'd rather not to. )

I believe .NET Framework does support the same feature as well. ( am I wrong? )

================================================================================

Okay, The question is really simple.

`$("#loginForm").attr("action", "/loginProcess.mon");`

when I submit the form, Spring framework catches the url and find the matched method @requestmapping annotation is attached to.

this works in Java, **But how to do in a pure asp.net web project ?**

=================================================================================

Since Javascript does almost everything, It's fair to say it's a client sided application.
so it's extremely important for me to keep the codes in .js file as same as possible in both Java and .NET version.

That why I desperately want the same thing to happen in both platforms while running the submit action.

```
$("#loginForm").attr("action", "/loginProcess.mon");
```

please help me out.

Comment: You might want to look at ASP.NET Routing:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd535618(v=vs.100).aspx.  Introduced as part of MVC, this is now also available in WebForms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked it but I'm afraid It's not what I'm looking for... my login page is a pure html page, it's not aspx or cshtml.

Comment: What will handle the posted form data from the login page?  An ASP.NET web service?

Comment: Yes, web service ( asmx or just .cs ) processes it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ASP webservice, then its simple. You just enable the GET method:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Then call the URL - something like:

```
http://example.com/MyWebService.asmx/MyAction?myparam1=something&myparam2=somethingelse
```

If you want to simplify/change the format, you can also try the IIS rewrite module: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

This allows you to configure rules at the web.config level to map URLs between one format and another, so you can create a more friendly URL.

Comment: Sorry I think it's not matter of rewriting url. I don't want just url to change when my app loads another resource, I want to make url decide which controller's methods to be executed.

Comment: maybe you are missing the basics - enable HTTP Get?